# Mark existing variable as candiate for implicit method

Tags: scala, implicit

I try to write a method which should use a variable from the surrounding scope. The problem is that I cannot access the part of the code where the variable is defined. Something like this:

```
object Example extends App {

  val myvar = 1.0 // cannot change that code

  def myMethod()(implicit value:Double) = {
      print(value)
  }

  myMethod()
}
```

This fails because `myMethod` cannot find a suitable implicit for `value`.

is there a way to "mark" `value` as implicit after it has been defined, other than defining a new implicit variable pointing to `value`?

Background: We use Spark-Notebook where the `SparkContext` (named `sc`) is created automatically. As `sc` is a commonly known name for this variable in the community, we would prefer not to introduce another variable name.

Comment: what's wrong with `implicit val myvarAgain = myvar`?

Comment: @EduardoParejaTobes I'd like not to introduce an additional variable...

Comment: `myMethod()(myvar)`

Comment: What you want to do is to pass the spark context implicitly to a method? Why not explicitly?

Comment: (Spark Notebook dev here) If you *really* *realliy* need the implicit, consider changing the source code and making a custom build: https://github.com/andypetrella/spark-notebook/blob/master/conf/scripts/init.sc#L143

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just don't want to have an instance of `SparkContext` that isn't labeled as `sc` you could assign it to an implicit-underscore variable like this:

```
implicit val _: SparkContext = sc
```

That would create an implicit variable of the correct type in scope for your function to use.

---

Alternatively you can always pass implicit variables explicitly, in your example above you could do

```
myMethod()(myvar)
```

and that is the solution that I would use.

Comment: `implicit val _` isn't an unnamed val. Its name is the underscore, and you can access it with back-ticks: `println(\`_\`)`. (Does not work in the REPL)

Comment: Cool thanks, I didn't know you could access it like that!  I will edit my answer.